# How can a /dev/one be created on CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos7, device-driver

I usually do the following on faulty hard-disks, before discarding them:

```
# lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0  2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0  2.7T  0 part 
# part=b
# for disk in /dev/sd[$part] ; do  echo ${disk};  echo "zero" ;  dd if=/dev/zero | pv | dd of=${disk}1 bs=99M iflag=fullblock ;  echo "urandom" ;  dd if=/dev/urandom | pv | dd of=${disk}1 bs=99M iflag=fullblock ;  echo "one" ;  dd if=<(yes $'\xFF' | tr -d '\n') | dd of=${disk}1 bs=99M iflag=fullblock  status=progress ;  done
```

Which will write a `0`, a random `0`/`1`, and a `1` on each byte of the disk. That should be enough to erase the data, if those trying to recover it aren't the NSA or the Mossad.

However, inputting `/dev/zero` and `/dev/urandom`, are *much* faster than `<(yes $'\xFF' | tr -d '\n')`.

**Is there a way to create a device on CentOS that will do for `1`, the equivalent that is done for `0` with `/dev/zero`?**

### Edit:

A faster way of getting a stream of ones is `if=<(cat /dev/zero | tr "\000" "\377")`, i.e.:

```
dd if=<(cat /dev/zero | tr "\000" "\377") | dd of=${disk}1 bs=99M iflag=fullblock status=progress ;
```

Answer (score 0):

/dev/zero and /dev/null are just device files linked to a device driver (created with mknod)

For an identical implementation you'd have to create device driver to do this.